# Stripe Firebase Extension - onCurrentUserPaymentUpdate not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I'm building a React App where you users can make one-time purchases of in-game tokens using Stripe. I'm having trouble getting `onCurrentUserPayment()` to work from the `@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments` sdk.

**CODE**

I have an `onClick button` event with the following code.

```
  const buyTokens1 = async () => {
      const session = await createCheckoutSession(payments, {
        mode: "payment",
        price: [PRICE_ID],
        success_url: window.location.origin,
        cancel_url: window.location.origin,
      });
      window.location.assign(session.url);

      onCurrentUserPaymentUpdate(payments, async (snapshot) => {
        for (const change in snapshot.changes) {
          if (change.type === "added") {
            const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
            await updateDoc(docRef, {
              tokens: authUser.tokens + 100,
            });
          }
        }
      });

  };
```

**PROBLEM**

When I click the button, the stripe checkout works perfectly fine, but the `onCurrentUserPaymentUpdate()` does not work.

It's supposed to execute the firebase `updateDoc` function when the Stripe purchase finishes, but it is not doing it.

The documentation isn't super clear. I've tried changing the "change-type" if statement and switching up API keys. None of this has worked.

Help!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you meant to listen for Stripe subscription update events through [**onCurrentUserSubscriptionUpdate**](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/tree/master/firestore-stripe-web-sdk#listen-for-subscription-updates) I don't find any `@stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions` package.

Comment: Ahh yes, but I'm looking to listen for Stripe payment events, not subscription events. I tried using `OnCurrentUserSubscriptionUpdate` and that didn't work either.

Also my bad and edited. It was `@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments` like you had linked.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to get `onCurrentUserPaymentUpdate` to work, so instead I leaned on Firebase [onSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) event listeners in order to track for the `payment collection` to update.

Once I did, I updated the document.

**See Code Below**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const paymentQ = query(
      collection(db, "users", user.uid, "payments"),
      where("status", "==", "succeeded"),
    );

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(paymentQ, (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach(async (change) => {
     if (change.type === "added") {
        if (authUser) {
           const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);

           await updateDoc(docRef, {
              kTokens: authUser?.kTokens + 100,
             });
           }
         }
       }
      });
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [authUser]);
```